# What does `NotFullyLoaded` error mean in candyMachine

Tags: metaplex, candy-machine-v3, candymachine

I am trying to call the `MintV2` candy machine instruction, but I am getting the error below originating from the Guard program.

Here is the code first

```
async function createCandyMachine() {
    const candyMachine = generateSigner(umi);//! ONLY USE WHEN CREATING NEW CANDY MACHINE
    let tx = await create(umi, {
        candyMachine,
        collectionMint: collectionMint,
        collectionUpdateAuthority: umi.identity,
        tokenStandard: TokenStandard.NonFungible,
        sellerFeeBasisPoints: percentAmount(9.99, 2), // 9.99%
        itemsAvailable: 50,
        creators: [
            {
                address: umi.identity.publicKey,
                verified: true,
                percentageShare: 100,
            },
        ],
        configLineSettings: some({
            prefixName: '',
            nameLength: 32,
            prefixUri: '',
            uriLength: 200,
            isSequential: false,
        }),
    });

    tx.sendAndConfirm(umi);
}

async function mintFromCandyMachine() {
    const candyMachine = await fetchCandyMachine(umi, publicKey("ErsrkFwzmCJSBfWts4PXdcCKmVUXwKy5sjrwFfRZChPR"));

    // add items to our candy machine
    await addConfigLines(umi, {
        candyMachine: candyMachine.publicKey,
        index: 0,
        configLines: [
            {
                name: 'Kobeni 1',
                uri: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/687c/solana-nft-native-client/main/metadata.json',
            },
            {
                name: 'Kobeni 2',
                uri: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/687c/solana-nft-native-client/main/metadata.json',
            },
            {
                name: 'Kobeni 3',
                uri: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/687c/solana-nft-native-client/main/metadata.json',
            }
        ]
    }).sendAndConfirm(umi);

    await transactionBuilder()
        .add(setComputeUnitLimit(umi, { units: 800_000 }))
        .add(mintV2(umi, {
            candyMachine: candyMachine.publicKey,
            nftMint: nftMint.publicKey,
            collectionMint: collectionMint,
            collectionUpdateAuthority: umi.identity.publicKey,
        }))
        .sendAndConfirm(umi)
}
```

and the error logs

```
    logs: [
      'Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]',
      'Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 success',
      'Program Guard1JwRhJkVH6XZhzoYxeBVQe872VH6QggF4BWmS9g invoke [1]',
      'Program log: Instruction: MintV2',
      'Program CndyV3LdqHUfDLmE5naZjVN8rBZz4tqhdefbAnjHG3JR invoke [2]',
      'Program log: Instruction: MintV2',
      'Program log: AnchorError thrown in program/src/instructions/mint_v2.rs:219. Error Code: NotFullyLoaded. Error Number: 6020. Error Message: Not all config lines were added to the candy machine.',
      'Program CndyV3LdqHUfDLmE5naZjVN8rBZz4tqhdefbAnjHG3JR consumed 29254 of 752695 compute units',
      'Program CndyV3LdqHUfDLmE5naZjVN8rBZz4tqhdefbAnjHG3JR failed: custom program error: 0x1784',
      'Program Guard1JwRhJkVH6XZhzoYxeBVQe872VH6QggF4BWmS9g consumed 76559 of 800000 compute units',
      'Program Guard1JwRhJkVH6XZhzoYxeBVQe872VH6QggF4BWmS9g failed: custom program error: 0x1784'
    ]
  },
  program: {
    name: 'mplCandyGuard',
    publicKey: 'Guard1JwRhJkVH6XZhzoYxeBVQe872VH6QggF4BWmS9g',
    getErrorFromCode: [Function: getErrorFromCode],
    getErrorFromName: [Function: getErrorFromName],
    isOnCluster: [Function: isOnCluster],
    availableGuards: [
      'botTax',           'solPayment',
      'tokenPayment',     'startDate',
      'thirdPartySigner', 'tokenGate',
      'gatekeeper',       'endDate',
      'allowList',        'mintLimit',
      'nftPayment',       'redeemedAmount',
      'addressGate',      'nftGate',
      'nftBurn',          'tokenBurn',
      'freezeSolPayment', 'freezeTokenPayment',
      'programGate',      'allocation',
      'token2022Payment'
    ]
  },
  logs: [
    'Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 invoke [1]',
    'Program ComputeBudget111111111111111111111111111111 success',
    'Program Guard1JwRhJkVH6XZhzoYxeBVQe872VH6QggF4BWmS9g invoke [1]',
    'Program log: Instruction: MintV2',
    'Program CndyV3LdqHUfDLmE5naZjVN8rBZz4tqhdefbAnjHG3JR invoke [2]',
    'Program log: Instruction: MintV2',
    'Program log: AnchorError thrown in program/src/instructions/mint_v2.rs:219. Error Code: NotFullyLoaded. Error Number: 6020. Error Message: Not all config lines were added to the candy machine.',
    'Program CndyV3LdqHUfDLmE5naZjVN8rBZz4tqhdefbAnjHG3JR consumed 29254 of 752695 compute units',
    'Program CndyV3LdqHUfDLmE5naZjVN8rBZz4tqhdefbAnjHG3JR failed: custom program error: 0x1784',
    'Program Guard1JwRhJkVH6XZhzoYxeBVQe872VH6QggF4BWmS9g consumed 76559 of 800000 compute units',
    'Program Guard1JwRhJkVH6XZhzoYxeBVQe872VH6QggF4BWmS9g failed: custom program error: 0x1784'
  ],
  code: 6020
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you have `itemsAvailable: 50`, you need to add 50 items (config lines) to the candy machine before you can mint.

You might have to make multiple calls to `addConfigLines()` if all of them won't fix in a single tx.

Comment: It seems that there is no way of avoiding the `itemsAvailable: 50,` field. Is there a way I can have it and not encounter the error?

Comment: You have to change `50` to the number of nfts you want in the candy machine.
If you want 3 nfts, set that to 3.